# How do I use the DOM in JS to insert HTML headers for returning JSON files?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I have a script that connects to a webservice that looks up artists and returns songs using JSON data.

I know how to use appendChild etc to return static text in a vacuum but I have a foreach loop that returns all the results from a database, within which I have to use the DOM to insert things like "Artist:" before the JSON variable.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/21txhmr6/

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", sendAjax);
}

function sendAjax() {
    var a = document.getElementById('artist').value;

    var ajaxConnection = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var newDiv = document.createElement("P");
    var newArtist = document.createTextNode("Artist:");
    var newSong = document.createTextNode("Song:");
    var newDownloads = document.createTextNode("Downloads:");

    newDiv.appendChild(newArtist);
    document.body.appendChild(newArtist);

    ajaxConnection.addEventListener ("load", e => {
        var output = "";
        var artistList = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);

        artistList.forEach( curArtist => {
              output = output + `${newArtist}  ${curArtist.artist}</td> <td>Title: ${curArtist.title}</td> <td>Downloads: ${curArtist.downloads}</td></table>`
        });

        document.getElementById('jsonload').innerHTML = output;
    });
    // Open the connection to a given remote URL.
    ajaxConnection.open("GET", `https://edward2.solent.ac.uk/~aelsbury/wadwebsite/htwebservice.php?artist=${a}`);

    // Send the request.
    ajaxConnection.send();
}
```

Comment: thats not valid html theres no opening tags?

Comment: you havent supplied the html for this to work add in your html to the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code seems to be the fact, that you create an invalid HTML structure in your loop. Each entry in the list should create a complete table row, I suppose, so just do that:

```
output = output + `<tr><td>${newArtist}  ${curArtist.artist}</td> <td>Title: ${curArtist.title}</td> <td>Downloads: ${curArtist.downloads}</td></tr>`
```

and place the `<table>` tags around the complete output, for example in the assignment to `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('jsonload').innerHTML = `<table>${output}</table>`;
```

It would be even better to not create HTML code, but DOM elements. This results in longer code, but makes sure that the structure is correct. You already do so for your `newDiv` element, just do it for the table rows and columns as well and you would not get such problems.